# My Flutter app doesn't receive API data on some devices

Tags: laravel, flutter, api

I am working on the flutter app, and I recently implemented authentication.
The app works fine on my phone in both release and debugs mode, but on some devices, when the user signs up or tries to log in, it shows buffering and doesn't open the next page. That's mainly because the app can't receive data from API. However, sending and receiving data works fine on the postman, so I don't know how to fix this.

Here, the problem is that this function works fine with me, but some users do not work. The main problem is that I can't see the error on the console because it doesn't happen on all my devices. It occurs only on some remote client devices. Also, sending and receiving data is working fine on the Postman.

```
Future<ResponseModel> companyRegistration(CompanySignUpModel signUpModel) async {
_isLoading = true;
_registrationErrorMessage = '';
notifyListeners();


ApiResponse apiResponse = await authRepo.companyRegisteration(signUpModel);
ResponseModel responseModel;
if (apiResponse.response != null && apiResponse.response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map map = apiResponse.response.data;
  String token = map["token"];
 
  final applicationDocumentDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(applicationDocumentDir.path);
  await Hive.openBox('myBox');
  var box = Hive.box('myBox');
  box.put('company_token', token);

  authRepo.saveCompanyToken(token);
  await authRepo.updateCompanyToken();
  responseModel = ResponseModel(true, 'successful');
} else {
  String errorMessage;
  if (apiResponse.error is String) {
    errorMessage = apiResponse.error.toString();
  } else {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = apiResponse.error;
    errorMessage = errorResponse.errors[0].message;
  }
  print(errorMessage);
  _registrationErrorMessage = errorMessage;
  responseModel = ResponseModel(false, errorMessage);
}
_isLoading = false;
notifyListeners();
return responseModel;
```

}

Comment: I would first take a look at the server's logs and then log client errors to somewhere e.g. https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add Sentry SDK to your app ? [sentry_flutter - Flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/sentry_flutter) it will report crashes and exceptions to [Sentry.io](https://sentry.io) so you can analyze them also you will get helpful info the snippet of code that code the error, the device model, device's network state ...